# Start action "StartAction" is not supported in the community edition of VoltDB

Tags: cluster-computing, startup, voltdb

I want to add a node to voltdb cluster, use command

```
voltdb start --add --host=s7biapp26
```

but, encountered a error about:

```
ERROR: Start action "StartAction" is not supported in the community edition of VoltDB.
FATAL: This process will exit. Please run VoltDB with the CREATE start action.
VoltDB has encountered an unrecoverable error and is exiting.
```

My voltdb version is **voltdb-community-8.0**

So, How to add a node to cluster for community version? What does mean about **"Please run VoltDB with the CREATE start action."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at VoltDB. The community edition does not support the feature to elastically scale out the cluster with no downtime, which is invoked using the "voltdb start --add" command. This feature is available on the enterprise edition.

With community edition, you can reconfigure the cluster (to add more nodes) using the process described in the [Admin Guide 4.3.4 Reconfiguring the Cluster During a Maintenance Window.](https://docs.voltdb.com/AdminGuide/MaintainUpgradeHw.php#MaintainUpgradeRestart)